# Creating and Implementing Classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, c++11, header, inline

In my computer science class we are learning how to use classes to create virtual electrical components... There are five things we need to create; the main() as well as ElectricalComponent.h/.cpp, Resistor.h/.cpp, Capacitor.h/.cpp, and Battery.h/.cpp.

I have already created the Electrical component Class, and I know how to create and fix any errors in the main function, however I am having trouble building the Resistor Class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ElectronicComponent.h"
class Resistor :
    public ElectronicComponent
{
public:
    Resistor(double);
    virtual ~Resistor();
    virtual double getValue() const = 0;
    virtual std::string getUnits() const = 0;
    virtual std::string to_string() const = 0;
};

Resistor::Resistor(double v)
{
    value = v;
}

std::string Resistor::to_string() const
{
    return "Resistor value (" + std::to_string(value) + " " + units + ")";
}
```

I am receiving the errors that namespace std has no member to_string, and that my variables value and units are undeclared.  I understand what it means by undeclared variables, but not the to_string error.

This is all the information that I was given regarding this Class:

> The Resistor class will be implemented with files Resistor.h and
>   Resistor.cpp. The Resistor class will inherit, publicly, from
>   ElectronicComponent. You need to implement a destructor and the three
>   virtual functions getValue, getUnits and to_string. You will also need
>   a constructor that takes one input parameter, the value of the
>   resistor. The value is of type double. The getValue function needs to
>   return the value as a double. The getUnits function needs to return
>   “Ohm(s)” as a std::string.

The rest of the classes should be built the same way, so understanding how one works should help me out a lot.  Thanks.

Comment: How are you compiling it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your header use:

```
#include<string>
```

Answer (score 1):

The functions in your derived Resistor class should not be specified as pure virtual functions (signified by the "=0"). Pure virtual functions are functions within a base class which have no base class implementation. Also, presumably your **getValue** and **getUnits** functions are not pure virtual in your ElectronicComponent base class, but are actually implemented there as:

```
double ElectronicComponent::getValue() const {
    return value;
}
std::string ElectronicComponent::getUnits() const {
    return units;
}
```

in which case you do not need them in your derived classes. So, your derived Resistor class should look something like:

```
#include <string>
#include "ElectronicComponent.h"
class Resistor : public ElectronicComponent
{
public:
    Resistor(double);
    virtual ~Resistor();
    virtual std::string to_string() const;
};

Resistor::Resistor(double v) : units("Ohm(s)")
{
    value = v;
}

std::string Resistor::to_string() const
{
    return "Resistor value (" + std::to_string(value) + " " + units + ")";
}
```